# Django: How to write migrations that don't require keyboard input?

Tags: django, deployment, database-migration

I'm wondering if there's a way to write migrations that won't ask me for input at the terminal. For example, while writing a migration that deletes a model, Django asks me to confirm this at the command line with a yes/no. I want to avoid these prompts because the same code will be used for *automatic* deployments (can't type in prompts during *automatic* deployment).

I'm aware there's the `noinput` option. I'm more interested in learning how to write migrations that don't require keyboard input, if possible. I've also noted that sometimes even when using this option, I get prompted anyway (one example that comes to mind was a migration that asked me to input default data for new columns being added to the model; `noinput` didn't stop Django from asking for my input anyway).

Answer (score 6):

There are two situations here: `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

`migrate` is 100% covered by the `--noinput` option: unless you install a custom, third-party pre/post migrate signal hook that ignores the option, you'll get no user prompts with this option.

`makemigrations` is not 100% covered by the `--noinput` option, and while it's a nice-to-have, it's absolutely not necessary. Migrations should **always** be created and tested in your development environment. I've yet to see a development environment where you can't provide manual input.

1.9 will in time introduce better support for the `--noinput` in combination with `makemigrations` (at the moment, it only supports `--noinput` in combination with `--merge`).

Comment: There's just one situation here. I'm asking if there's a way to write a migration that will run without prompting for keyboard input.

Comment: @Proto There are two. You ask about `migrate`, but you reject the solution because that same solution doesn't work for `makemigrations`. The situation you're asking about has nothing to do with the situation you describe as "not working".

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. I'm only asking if there is a way to write migrations such that I'm not prompted for keyboard input at the terminal. Perhaps you could explain how what you're saying answers that question. It's not clear to me how what you say is a solution to the question I'm asking.

Comment: @Proto Do you want to run `manage.py migrate` without user input, or `manage.py makemigrations` with no user input? Unless I'm indeed misunderstanding your question, you're asking about the first case, and I refer to the first part of my answer: `--noinput` is the solution, and it works 100% of the time. If you're asking about the second case, I refer to the second part of my answer: you can't, and you should never run this in automatic deployment. If you're asking about both: you have two situations, and I refer to respectively the first and second part of my answer.

Comment: @Proto *you* are the one who is misunderstanding. You are never asked for keyboard input when you *run* migrations, only when you *create* them. And there is no situation where you would ever be creating migrations on a system with no keyboard input.

Comment: knbk: I'm asking if I create a migration file and manually write the changes I want, is there a way to write it that would prevent keyboard prompts, only asking if its possible. Thanks for your patience. @DanielRoseman Best to ask for clarification than assume the questioner doesn't know what they want to know. You just answered my question: "And there is no situation where you would ever be creating migrations on a system with no keyboard input." You're saying there's no way to *write* a migration file that would prevent Django from asking for input. That's exactly what I'm asking. Thanks.

Comment: >  I've yet to see a development environment where you can't provide manual input.
I have one, it's called docker-machine on windows. I can run django commands but they can't be interactive or assigned a tty. So even if I run makemigrations with --noinput it still doesn't work. noinput should be noinput if I know what I'm doing.
Note this is fixed in django 1.9 anyways https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23407